# Odoo 10 use configuration value (stored in ir.values) inside XML

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create a menu in the sidebar which shows products of a specific category. I was thinking to use a filter for this task, which is set by default.

However, I don't know how to use the value of my configuration inside my XML domain.

Here is how my XML code looks like:

```
<record id="my_product_search_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Products Of My Category Search</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//search" position="inside">
            <filter string="My Category" name="filter_my_categ" domain="[('categ_id','child_of',my_category)]"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="my_product_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Products Of My Category</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.template</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_my_categ":1}</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="my_product_search_form_view" />
</record>

<menuitem id="menu_my_products" name="Products Of my Category"
      parent="menu_product" action="my_product_action"
       />
```

I hoped, that when adding 'my_category' to the ir.values table with the model 'product.template' the value will somehow be added to the context - which is not the case & I get an Odoo Client Error **NameError: name 'my_category' is not defined**

Does anyone know how I can use values of the ir.values table inside my XML view - or at least call a python method inside the `context` or `domain` tags? Or is there another solution for my task? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in odoo v8 and it works for me.

First create your filter without domain only with context.

```
<filter string="My Category" name="filter_my_categ" domain="[]" context="{'custom_filter':1}"/>
```

Then i inherited the search method like this.

```
def search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None,context=None, count=False):                        
        if context.get('custom_filter',False):
            state = self.pool.get('ir.values').get_default(cr, uid, 'sale.order', 'dyn_filter')
            args.append(['state','=',state])
        result= super(sale_order_ext, self).search(cr, uid, args=args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order,
            context=context, count=count)

    return result
```

That's all.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the solution in Odoo8 (posted by Viki Chavada), here is how the python code looks like for Odoo 10 & extending the product.template:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    @api.model
    def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False):
        if self.env.context.get('custom_filter', False):
            category = self.env['ir.values'].get_default('my.config', 'my_category')
            args.append(['categ_id', 'child_of', category])

        result = super(ProductTemplate, self).search(args=args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)

        return result
```